# Create a customer from Devise User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How can I create a customer class I want to be a Devise User with a role = 1.

I have my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:user, :customer, :admin, :producer]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable, :registerable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

And my Customer model

```
class Customer < User

end
```

I can specify in the customersController what is a customer like this :

```
# GET /customers
def index
  @customers = Customer.where(:role => 1).page(params[:page])
end
```

But How can I modify my Customer model to self know he is a User with role = 1 so I can only get my Customers like this :

```
@customers = Customer.all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you exactly need `Customer.all` you should looking for STI(single table inheritance) which already resolve what you trying to do

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look on it.